# Is there an easier version of this SQL script?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run a script on an Oracle Database via SQL Developer. There are five columns: `ID`, `LAST_NAME`, `FIRST_NAME`, `USERID`, and `SALARY`. This is the code I've written to accept values and edit the `USERID` field with the lowercase of the 1st letter of the `FIRST_NAME` and the whole `LAST_NAME`.

```
INSERT INTO ACT_MY_EMPLOYEE
    VALUES (&P_ID, '&P_LAST_NAME', '&P_FIRST_NAME',
    LOWER(SUBSTR('&P_FIRST_NAME', 1, 1) ||
    SUBSTR('&P_LAST_NAME', 1, 7)), &P_SALARY);
```

Is there an easier version to this? Thank you!

Comment: you've not specified the whole last name.. just first 7 chars!

Comment: Hi @VianyManuel so this query works for you in Oracle ? You just want to find a better sollution ? Please can you share with us what values do you insert in table ACT_MY_EMPLOYEE ? Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad @JGFMK . I'll change that. Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka, yes, it works for Oracle Database, and yes, I do want to find a better solution where I don't get prompts (which was answered a little while back, for which I'm sorry to have replied late). This is actually a tester database problem which really took me a while to understand but was clearly answered below. Thank you for replying though! :smiley:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use `&&` instead of `&` as single `&` will ask you for the value each time it is uses in your sql while double `&` will store substitution value (asks for value only once) and use it if same variable is used second time in the same session.

```
INSERT INTO ACT_MY_EMPLOYEE
    VALUES (&P_ID, '&&P_LAST_NAME', '&&P_FIRST_NAME',
    LOWER(SUBSTR('&&P_FIRST_NAME', 1, 1) ||
    SUBSTR('&&P_LAST_NAME', 1, 7)), &P_SALARY);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This did it! Thank you for this. So, that's how it works. I'm probably going to use this knowledge for quite some time. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stored procedure would be a good idea, especially if you frequently add new rows. Instead of keeping the `INSERT INTO` statement in some script (and have to remember where you put it), a procedure is permanently stored in the database.

It might look like this:

```
create or replace procedure p_ins_ame (
   par_id          in act_my_employee.id%type,
   par_first_name  in act_my_employee.first_name%type,
   par_last_name   in act_my_employee.last_name%type,
   par_salary      in act_my_employee.salary%type)
is
begin
   insert into act_my_employee (id,
                                last_name,
                                first_name,
                                some_column,
                                salary)
           values (
                     par_id,
                     par_last_name,
                     par_first_name,
                     lower (
                           substr (par_first_name, 1, 1)
                        || substr (par_last_name, 1, 7)),
                     par_salary);
END;
```

You'd call it as

```
begin
  p_ins_ame (par_id         => 100,
             par_first_name => 'Little',
             par_last_name  => 'Foot',
             par_salary     => 1000);
end;
```

Of course, it can be further developed so that it inserts a sequence number instead of a "fixed" `ID` value (or, if your database version supports it, use an `identity` column). Any changes you make will be used in all subsequent procedure calls.

---

As of a single `INSERT INTO` statement: as you've already been told, certain tools (such as SQL*Plus) allow you to use two ampersands (`&&`) along with the variable name. It means that you won't be prompted to enter the same variable's value twice (or as many times as it appears in that script), but only once.

That's OK, just beware! If you enter a slash (`/`) at the prompt and hit the `ENTER` key, you'll insert the same row once again (unless it fails on uniqueness). Don't forget to **UNDEFINE** those variables!

Comment: I see. So this is actually a better way to solve the problem. I'm still not familiar with procedures and how to execute/save them inside the database, but I'll be sure to check it out. Thank you!